# Funcion con md5 no funciona, no encuentro el error. Alguien que me de una manito

Tags: php

EXPLICO DETALLE:
Hola estoy siguiendo un tutorial para poder crear una ruta encryptada para que el cliente pueda ver su orden, pero no entiendo muy bien justo esta parte. En el tutorial desde un modelo Shoppingcart se crea esta función:

```
 public function approved(){
            $this->updateCustomId();
        }

        public function generateCustomId(){
            $this->id;
            return md5("$this->id $this->updated_at");
        }

        public function updateCustomId(){
            $this->customid = $this->generateCustomId();
            $this->save();
        }
```

en el controlador tiene

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $shopping_cart_id=\session::get('shopping_cart_id');
    
    $shopping_cart=Shoppingcart::findOrCreateSessionID($shopping_cart_id);
    
    $paypal=new Paypal($shopping_cart);
    $response = $paypal->execute($request->paymentId,$request->PayerID);
    
    if($response->state=="approved"){
    $order = Order::createFromPaypalResponse($response,$shopping_cart);
        
    $shoppin_cart->approved();
    //AQUI SE REALIZA LA FUNCION Y ENTIENDO QUE LO QUE GUARDA COMO ID ES 
    //EL ID DE LA SESSION SHOPPING_CART EN EL CAMPO customid
    // DE LA BASE PERO  ENCRYPTADA COMO MD5 Y UN UPDATE
    }
```

Yo estoy tratando de implementar en mi proyecto algo parecido, en mi    caso:

YO CREE TAMBIEN EL CAMPO customId TENGO EL ID DE LA ORDEN GUARDADO EN LA VARIABLE $id, ES POR ESO QUE LE APLICO LA FUNCIÓN approved(), PERO COMO COMENTO ME SALE EL ERROR

```
 public function pay(Request $request)
    {
        $payment_id = $request->get('payment_id');
        $payment_name = $request->get('name');

        $response = Http::get("Https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/$payment_id"." access_token=".env('MP_ACCESS_TOKEN'));

        //dd($response = json_decode($response));
        $response = json_decode($response);

        $status=$response->status;

        if($status=='approved'){

            $order = Order::createFromMercadoPagoResponse($response);
            

            $id = Order::where('id_payment_mercadopago',$payment_id)->pluck('id')->first            ();
            
            $items = Item::createItemsFromMercadoPagoResponse($response, $id);

            $id->approved();
            //LA MISMA FUNCION QUE EL TUTORIAL LA TENGO EN EL MODELO
            //YO NO TENGO UNA ID DE SESSION COMO EN EL CASO DEL 
            //TUTORIAL, LO QUE TENGO ES LA ID DE LA ORDEN QUE ENTIENDO 
            //SE  DEBERÍA ENCRYPTAR Y GUARDAR EN LA BASE EN EL CAMPO 
            //custonid
            //AL PARECER NO ENTIENDO LA LÓGICA, SI POR AHI ALGUIEN ME 
            //AYUDA , ME FALTA ESTO
        }
```

Se supone que la función debería convertir el numero de la id a Md5

Si se necesita más que agregue más código solo indicar y actualizaré la consulta. Muchas Gracias

Comment: Si `$id` le asignas `5`, por qué supones que `$id` es una instancia de la clase con todos los métodos del modelo? Esa variable representa un entero en ese momento... Tal vez sólo tienes que ejecutar `generateCustomId()` sin más, suponiendo que el id es un atributo de la clase donde está definido el método

Comment: Hola Alfabravo, actualicé la pregunta, yo estoy queriendo implementar ese paso desde un tutorial que tengo, ahi estoy poniendo el detalle del paso como lo implementan en el tutotial y el porque de la $id, si me pudieras explicar un poquito más sería hipergenial,, lo que se necesite puedo agregar a la pregunta para que se entienda más. Te agradezco igual

Comment: En tu codigo estas obteniendo el Order des una consulta (cojes el primer order con el first()). y luego quieres aplicar a ese order (que has llamado $id) la funcion approved(). Tenemos que ver si el modelo Order tiene esas tres funciones. Cual es el error que dices que te da?